# Can I somehow display git file statuses in sidebar in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: git, user-interface, sublime-text-3, atom-editor

I've seen this cool feature in Atom, where in bottom left corner Git status is displayer (like which branch, how many files changed etc) and in the sidebar files that are created but not added and changed files are shown in green and yellow color.

Is there any way to achieve something like this in Sublime Text 3?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, due to the lack of a proper sidebar API, this is not currently possible with Sublime. However, there are [a number](https://packagecontrol.io/search/git) of different git-related plugins for Sublime that do things like provide a git menu when right-clicking in the sidebar, showing git diff icons in the gutter (next to the line numbers) showing what's been changed since the last commit, a customizable git status bar showing the state of the repo to which the current file belongs, and a lot more. Hopefully a better sidebar API will be added in a future release.